# How to format date for different language

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Now i have the english locale `en-US` and french locale `fr-CA`. How can i format a english date `05/31/2018` to french date `31/05/2018`?

Comment: Maybe [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: There is also the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) functionality.

Comment: "en-US" is an ISO 639 language code. The term "locale" is a misnomer.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to catch the actual datetime, you can do only **setDate()** with this function on your code:

```
 function setDate(dt){

    if(dt = "NaN"){
      var date = new Date();
    }else{
      var date = new Date(dt);
    }

    var language = navigator.language;
    var dateTime;

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    if(day < 10){
      day = `0${day}`;
    }

    if(month < 10){
      month = `0${month}`;
    }

    if(language == 'en-US'){
      dateTime = `${day}/${year}/${month}`;
    }else{
      dateTime = `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    }

    return dateTime;
  }
```

But, if you have an especific datetime, you can add on **console.log(setDate("05/31/2018"));**.

This function will return you the date formated.

Comment: The code has errors, and it doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Where are the errors?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PvLzeZ?editors=1111

Comment: `if (dt = "NaN")` will always resolve to true, it doesn't test whether *dt* is NaN and if corrected to `dt == NaN`, will always be false as NaN isn't equal to anything, even NaN (hence [*isNaN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)). `new Date(dt)` is a bad idea, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).

Comment: True, sorry to bored you, thanks for this.

Comment: No problem, most of the benefit of StackOverflow is to those who post answers. It's often more beneficial than asking a question. :-)